# SQL Pivot Multiple (15) Values returning in just 4 columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Microsoft SQL 2008r2

I have tried reviewing all the Pivot posts, Pivot with Multiple Values, but nothing seems to be what I need - this may be the closest [Displaying multiple values into columns in sql server using pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627959/displaying-multiple-values-into-columns-in-sql-server-using-pivot) - but sadly no "results" so I can't be sure.

**My question**

I'm have a database where I am querying 2 tables

GALFP       16421 rows, fairly static as a new room gets created (or populated) more values added - currently I'm only interested in 15 rows in here (see in grey further down below).

```
siteLabel               nvarchar    255 
siteConnectionString    nvarchar    255 
LanNo                   smallint    NULL 
NodeAddress             smallint    NULL 
LanLabel                nvarchar    255 
OSLabel                 nvarchar    255 
PointLabel              nvarchar    255 
item                    nvarchar    255 
pointID                 int         NULL
```

PV  23496777 rows, growing lots every 15 mins which is made up of

```
PointID         int         NULL 
DataTime        datetime    NULL 
DataValue       float       NULL 
DataValueType   tinyint     NULL 
DataValueStatus tinyint     NULL
```

I have 4 queries for reporting and they are selecting based on 4 liked values - but the 4 liked value return in total 15 combinations;

So here's 1 of the queries

```
SELECT  GALFP.PointLabel, PV,DataTime, ROUND(PV,DataValue, 2) AS MinTemp    **/* See note about the 4 values */**  
FROM    PL INNER JOIN GALFP ON PV,PointID = GALFP.pointID  
WHERE   convert(VARCHAR(10), PV.DataTime,110) like '03%2017'  AND  
    (GALFP.PointLabel LIKE N'%Data Hall%Min Temp (15 minute)%')     **/* See note about variants */**
```

**Values**: The 1st type is MinTemp (as shown), 2nd is MaxTemp, 3rd AvgTemp, 4th RelHumidity

So rather than running 4 queries and copy/paste - what I'd like to report is Label, Date/Time, Min, Max, Avg, RelHum - in a single query (if possible)

Simples I hear you say... pivot right? However the data and query get worse - you can see that the WHERE clause has a Like in it

**Variants**: So the current 15 possible values are

```
ALL Room 4 Hum Ave (15 minute)

Room 1 Min Temp (15 minute)
Room 2 Min Temp (15 minute)
Room 3 Min Temp (15 minute)
Room 5 Min Temp (15 minute)

Room 1 Max Temp (15 minute)
Room 2 Max Temp (15 minute)
Room 3 Max Temp (15 minute)
Room 5 Max Temp (15 minute)

Room 1 Hum Ave (15 minute)
Room 2 Hum Ave (15 minute)
Room 3 Hum Ave (15 minute)
Room 4 Hum Ave (15 minute)
Room 5 Hum Ave (15 minute)
Room 6 Hum Ave (15 minute)
```

So if I pivot on the 15 values, I get 15 columns which isn't what is needed. I need to be able to have all the Min in one column, Max in another, Average in another and Humidity in another, regardless of what room it relates to - though I do need to know what room it is, ready for reporting/graphs etc, so I can't eliminate that from the data.

Yes I know it could have been better normalised, its not my design :(

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to get closer to what you want. Without sample data, I worked with what I could from your example values of `galfp.PointLabel`.

If you have a single data point for a given `pv`, `room` and `datatime`, then the aggregations below are simply removing nulls.

Instead of converting your dates to a string to use a `like` comparison, you can truncate the date to a month using `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,  pv.DataTime), 0)` and compare that the desired month.

```
select 
    pv
  , DataTime
  , Room    = left(galfp.PointLabel,patindex('%[0-9] %',galfp.PointLabel)
  , MinTemp = max(case when galfp.PointLabel like N'%Min Temp%' then round(pv.DataValue, 2) end)
  , MaxTemp = max(case when galfp.PointLabel like N'%Max Temp%' then round(pv.DataValue, 2) end)
  , AvgTemp = max(case when galfp.PointLabel like N'%Avg Temp%' then round(pv.DataValue, 2) end)
  , HumAve  = max(case when galfp.PointLabel like N'%Hum Ave%'  then round(pv.DataValue, 2) end)
from pl 
  inner join galfp on pv.Pointid = galfp.pointid
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,  pv.DataTime), 0) = '20170301' 
group by 
    pv
  , DataTime
  , left(galfp.PointLabel,patindex('%[0-9] %',galfp.PointLabel)
```